# below mentioned sentence is simple sentence or tense sentence?

Tags: grammar, british-english, tenses

Below mentioned sentence is "simple sentence" or "present indefinite" sentence

sumit is to go to park.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, a simple sentence doesn't preclude the present indefinite verb tense.

*Sumit parks cars* is both a simple sentence *and* is in the present indefinite. (But I doubt that's your intended meaning.)

However, the sentence you give is ungrammatical—that kind of construction isn't used.

Translating your sentence as much as I can, I can think of two likely variations.

> Sumit should go to the park.
>   Sumit is going to go to the park.

Both of these are examples of a simple sentence, but neither uses the present indefinite.

Comment: Situation is that sumit's father ordered him to go the park but sumit mother is unaware of it and want to send him for shopping, now sumit's father telling his mother that "sumit is to go to the park "

Comment: @kuldeepsingh The use of the article (*the* park) makes a big difference to the sentence. While this would now be understood in informal use, the two variations that I proposed would still be more commonly used. As with those, my answer would remain the same. It is a simple sentence but not an example of the present indefinite.

Answer (score -1):

First of all I m unable to understand the meaning of your sentence.
I think it's structure is somehow awkward.
So I m here trying to give you a hint about difference between simple present and present indefinite

Basically, they both are same Present Indefinite and Simple Present Tense. But there are some difference I will clear you with example.

He is a boy. (This is the Simple Present Tense)

When we use Is, Am, Are in Simple Present Tense, we don’t use action verb.

He eats food. (This is the Present indefinite Tense)

Comment: This may also help.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Going-to_future#The_be_+_to_construction

Comment: Situation is that sumit's father ordered him to go the park but sumit mother is unaware of it and want to send him for shopping, now sumit's father telling his mother that "sumit is to go to the park "